What should be the upper and lower limit for this inner integral of the double integral to be $0$?
This is the integral I am trying to solve.

$\large \mathbb P(X=Y) = \underset{x=y}{\int \int}f_{X, Y}(x, y ) dx dy = \underset{x>0, y>0,\\ x+y< 1,\ x=y}{\int \int} 4(x+y)^{2} dx dy$,
where $(X, Y)$ is a continuous random vector with pdf $f_{X,Y}(x, y)= 4(x+y)^{2} $.

I know that for a continuous random variable (or for a random vector) $\mathbb P(X=x)$ (or $\mathbb P(X=Y)$) is $0$.
Also, I understand the value of the double integral should be equal to $0$, since we are integrating a two-variable function on a one-dimensional set (the $y=x$ line is the range) but as I proceed to show that the value of the double integral is $0$ I get the upper limit and the lower limit of the inner integrals as $y$ and $1-y$ respectively, limit of $y$ is $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ and the final value of the double integral as $\frac12$ which  is intuitively wrong.

If the inner integral is $0$, then its limit should be from $y$ to $y$ but it is from $y$ to $1-y$. I am not sure if I am thinking in the right direction. Any help or explanation are highly appreciated, helpful and valuable. I do not need the full solution of the integral - I am only having problem with the limits of inner integral.

We have :
$\large \mathbb P(X=Y) = \underset{x=y}{\int \int}f_{X, Y}(x, y ) dx dy = \underset{x>0, y>0,\\ x+y< 1,\ x=y}{\int \int} 4(x+y)^{2} dx dy$
Yes , it is indeed the Case that $\mathbb P(X=x)$ & $\mathbb P(X=Y)$ is $0$
Here , $x=y$ & $x+y \le 1$ gives $ y+y \le 1$ , $y \le 0.5$
Hence Outer Integral has limits $0$ & $0.5$
Inner Integral is on the line $x=y$ (not $x \le y$ , not $x \ge y$)
Hence Inner Integral has limits $y$ & $y$
$\large \mathbb P(X=Y) = \underset{x=y}{\int \int}f_{X, Y}(x, y ) dx dy = \int_0^{0.5} \int_y^y 4(x+y)^{2} dx dy = \int_0^{0.5} [Z]_y^y dy = \int_0^{0.5} 0 dy = 0$
$\large \mathbb P(X=Y) = 0$

Thanks for the confirmation. +1 for the answer.

Some times , Third Party Confirmation just makes things a little bit easier , @TopoSet32 , while giving mental peace !
